# OrientDB "Cannot find a command executor for the command request" error

Tags: java, maven, orientdb, tinkerpop-blueprint

I originally posted this as a bug on the OrientDB [issue tracker](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5105). However, I'm not not so sure it's a bug...

Basically when I run the project from the IDE everything works great and all the queries get executed without a hitch. However, when I package up the project using `maven-shade-plugin` I start getting these `Cannot find a command executor for the command request:` errors but only for a subset of queries. In my `pom.xml` I declare the following:

```
<!-- As defined: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html  -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
    <artifactId>orientdb-core</artifactId>
    <version>${orientdb-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
    <artifactId>orientdb-graphdb</artifactId>
    <version>${orientdb-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tinkerpop.blueprints</groupId>
    <artifactId>blueprints-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
     <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
     <version>4.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
     <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
     <version>4.2.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap</groupId>
     <artifactId>concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru</artifactId>
     <version>1.4.2</version>
 </dependency>
<!-- Include to enable embedded db if user selects single mode -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
    <artifactId>orientdb-server</artifactId>
    <version>${orientdb-version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Include to enable remote db if user selects distributed mode -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
    <artifactId>orientdb-client</artifactId>
    <version>${orientdb-version}</version>
</dependency>
...
<orientdb-version>2.1.3</orientdb-version>
```

I've added the following filter to the shade plugin to try and make sure nothing is getting stripped out but it doesn't appear to have fixed the issue:

```
<filters>
    <filter>
        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
        <includes>
             <include>**</include>
        </includes>
   </filter>
</filters>
```

---

StackTrace:

```
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.CREATE EDGE hasRole FROM (SELECT FROM Person WHERE @rid=#15:0) TO (SELECT FROM Role WHERE @rid=#16:1)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:72) ~[halo-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:42) ~[halo-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.command(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1431) ~[halo-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:63) ~[halo-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphCommand.execute(OrientGraphCommand.java:49) ~[halo-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at co.ff36.halo.core.persistence.Dao.exec(Dao.java:94) ~[halo-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at co.ff36.halo.core.resource.server.UserRoleServerResource.store(UserRoleServerResource.java:63) ~[halo-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
```

Comment: do you have the stacktrace?

Comment: @wolf4ood Yep, added the relevant trace. Also not that it should be relevant but for completeness the error is coming from an `OCommandSQL`. `graph.command(new OCommandSQL("...")).execute();`

Comment: added the answer. With this you should solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that maven-shade-plugin is not able to merge the services files by default. OrientDB uses Java services to inject command with the same interface. I think if you see some log when building you will see that the shade plugin skip some file because they already exists. 
I think you can solve it adding some merge strategy

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ServicesResourceTransformer